# what special feature do have the attributes begin with @?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on a Elasticsearch index/type with some attributes that begin with @ p.e. @timestamp, @internalValue, so I would like to know if those attributes have some special feature or if they are good for something.

FYI the whole data in the index has been filled for a kind of script (in charge of pull out data from a RDBM and put it into ES) and logstash is not used in this process.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch doesn't have any special meaning for fields prefixed with `@`.

Logstash uses `@` to define metadata fields for the log, for example `@timestamp`. Since you are not using Logstash, there is no special meaning for `@` and they have no "special feature" - they are just normal fields.

Elasticsearch uses a prefix of `_`, for exmple `_id` for its own metadata fields.

Comment: it is also worth noting that you're not allowed to declare fields in your documents with the same name as the predefined fields in ES, i.e. `_id`, `_index`, `_type`, etc. ES will complain about it.